# Modular Arithmetic: Congruence System

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How to solve this congruence system:
        \begin{cases}  
x≡2 &\bmod3 \\
     2x≡1& \bmod5 \\ 
     3x≡3 &\bmod6
\end{cases}

Comment: Any thoughts?  If all else fails, the $\text {lcm}(3,5,6)=30$ so trial and error isn't difficult.

Comment: $3x\equiv 3\pmod{6}$ implies that $x$ is not even.  $x\equiv2\pmod{3}$ and $x$ is not even implies what $x$ must be $\pmod{6}$.  At this point, it is just a routine application of chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: You can find the last digit of $x$ from the two last equations.

Comment: $\bmod 3\!:\ x\equiv 2\iff \bmod 6\!:\ x\equiv 2,5\,$ but  $\,3x\equiv 3\,$ only for $\,x\equiv 5.\,$ Finally CRT that with $\bmod 5\!:\ 2x\equiv 1\equiv 6\iff x\equiv 3\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

$x\equiv 2 \pmod{3}$ is equivalent to say $x=2+3k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Substitute this into the second congruence and you have
$$2(2+3k)\equiv 1 \pmod{5}$$
or
$$k\equiv 2 \pmod{5}$$
Which means $k=2+5\ell$ and that $x=2+3(2+5\ell)=8+15\ell$ for $\ell\in \mathbb{Z}$. Finally, put this into the last congruence and then
$$3(8+15\ell)\equiv 3 \pmod{6}$$
which is simplified as
$$\ell\equiv1 \pmod{2}$$
or well $\ell=1+2t$ for some integer $t$. Therefore $x=8+15(1+2t)=23+30t$ or equivalently
$$x\equiv 23 \pmod{30}$$
and this is the solution.